# Video play using video tag with wowza media server

Tags: html, wowza

I am trying to play video on chrome using video tag (html5) this video is uploaded on wowza media server and its run on only mac in safari, it does'nt play on windows and even on chrome on mac, what can i do for playing video on chrome on windows , my code is

```
<video controls="controls" width="480" height="320">
    <source src="http://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:GettingStarted.mov/playlist.m3u8" />
</video>
```

i dont want to use flash to play video.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a different format for other browsers that don't support HLS.  I have not seen this work with Wowza and browsers' video tag, but there is an example using JwPlayer - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/player/trunk/fl5/js/test/examples/single_mp4.html.  Note that this does fall back to flash for Firefox and Opera.